# How Big is the Earthican Empire?

Tags: futurama

How **big** is the Earthican (Nation of Earth) Empire?

The only place Earth conquered that I remember are the small planets such as the silk planet (planet of spiders) from *"Three Hundred Big Boys"* and the ball planet from *"War is the H Word"*.

Comment: You can add Mars (Mars U) and the Moon to the list.

Answer (score 1):

The **Earthican empire** consists of Earth, the moon, Spheron I, Tarantulon 6, the intergalactic stock exchange, mars and Halley's comet (though the ice reserves were used up in 3003).